# Не могу найти свое приложение в Google Play

Tags: google-play

Не могу найти свое приложение в поиске ГП. ВВожу точное название, могу найти только по имени разработчика, и то оно где то снизу, в поиске приложения с абсолютно другим названием, хотя ввожу я точно свое. Что делать?